# Create a stream to read a huge string in GO

Tags: xml, go

I have a huge xml in a variable and a function to decode this xml. I can't use unmarshal because at a certain momment I need to read an element and add it immediately in the db.

Example:

```
db := mongo.Connect()

decoder := xml.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
defer resp.Body.Close()

for {
    token, _ := decoder.Token()
    if token == nil {
        break
    }

    switch se := token.(type) {
    case xml.StartElement:
    ...
}
```

But now I need to read from a string. So I don't have the resp.Body anymore but a string. The NewDecoder() function receives an io.Reader, so I think I can in read from a stream. How can I do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn any string into an `io.Reader` with the `strings.NewReader` method:

```
reader := strings.NewReader("some string")
```

Comment: Similar types exists in `bytes` for byte slices as well.